# How to predict new output from a linearRegression model build using sklean?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have been following  tutorial on linear regression with scikitlearn.The code works perfectly and now i wanna predict new output by giving a new input.I have used student score and Study hour data set.
Here's the code:

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data=pd.read_csv("/home/crpsm/Pycharm/DataSet/student_scores.csv")

data.plot(x="Hours",y="Scores",style="o")
plt.title("Score-Hour")
plt.xlabel('Hours ')
plt.ylabel('Percentage ')


x=data.iloc[:,:-1]
y=data.iloc[:,1]

 x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,train_size=0.55,random_state=5)

regression_model=LinearRegression()
regression_model.fit(x_train,y_train)

print(regression_model.coef_)
print(regression_model.intercept_)
regression_model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the issue and the question?

Comment: I have to predict a new output from a new input.if i give hours of study as 6 or 6or7,it need the output of the score predicted by the model like 67 or 78..like that!

Comment: Stop following the tutorial which you are following if it doesn't even teach you how to use the model to predict after fitting

Comment: @Bazingaa after following the tutorial it predicted values within the dataset,but how can i use it to predict the score by giving a new hour of study..

Comment: Let's say your new hour of study is in a variable called `new_hour`, then just use `y_new = regression_model.predict(new_hour)`. What's wrong with doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prediction = regression_model.predict(X)`

Please read the docs:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html